# how to rename a gDoc printer in Win 7 64 bit machines

Tags: printers

I have installed a printer called gDoc Creator for printing on my Windows 7 64 bit machines. If i rename the printer to anything other than "gDoc Creator" the printer is not recognized when I select it to print. It just becomes totally dead. It only works with the given name. I want to know how I can rename the printer and make it work successfully. I have tried renaming in the .inf files but I am yet to find a solution. Thanks all for your help and I appreciate the responses and please let me know if more details are required.

Answer (score 0):

If renaming the printer causes it to stop working, the driver must have that name hard-coded and depends on it never being changed.  That's a seriously broken printer driver if it actually cares what the printer name is and doesn't allow that name to be changed.  You can confirm that by opening the driver's two DLLs with a hex editor and looking for the string "gDoc Creator."  If it is as I suspect, there's nothing you can do short of patching the DLL, and frankly that's just not worth it.  There are many PDF/Office conversion tools out there.  I recommend you find a better one.